# Getting GET "?" Variable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest

Hello I'm creating an API using REST and Laravel following [this](http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/building-restful-api-in-laravel-start-here/) article.

Everything works well as expected.

Now, I want to map a GET request to recognise a variable using "?".

For example: `domain/api/v1/todos?start=1&limit=2`.

Below is the contents of my `routes.php` :

```
Route::any('api/v1/todos/(:num?)', array(
    'as'   => 'api.todos',
    'uses' => 'api.todos@index'
));
```

My `controllers/api/todos.php` :

```
class Api_Todos_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;

    public function get_index($id = null) {
        if(is_null($id)) {
            return Response::eloquent(Todo::all(1));

        } else {
            $todo = Todo::find($id);
            if (is_null($todo)) {
                return Response::json('Todo not found', 404);
            } else {
                return Response::eloquent($todo);   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I GET a parameter using "?" ?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Take a look at the [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [$_REQUEST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) superglobals. Something like the following would work for your example:

```
$start = $_GET['start'];
$limit = $_GET['limit'];
```

**EDIT**

According to [this post in the laravel forums](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=16363#p16363), you need to use `Input::get()`, e.g.,

```
$start = Input::get('start');
$limit = Input::get('limit');
```

See also: http://laravel.com/docs/input#input

Comment: You get way more functionality out of using Input::get, Input::has, Input::all, Input::file etc.
The only time I recommend using a super global is when you are uploading an array of files then you do need to use $_FILES.

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2016, the right way of using Input in Laravel's  >v5.0 is this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34642837/1067293

Comment: This is not the Laravel way of getting request parameters

Comment: Specify please the source of `Input`

Comment: It looks like instead of `Input` you're supposed to use `$request->input()`: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#input.  The shared link in the answer above 404s for me: http://laravel.com/docs/input#input

Comment: never use php superglobals with laravel because you may change laravel configuration that is using them.

Answer (score 46):

On 5.3-8.0 you reference the query parameter as if it were a member of the `Request` `class`.

#### 1. Url

`http://example.com/path?page=2`

#### 2. In a route callback or controller action using magic method Request::__get()

```
Route::get('/path', function(Request $request){
 dd($request->page);
}); 

//or in your controller
public function foo(Request $request){
 dd($request->page);
}

//NOTE: If you are wondering where the request instance is coming from, Laravel automatically injects the request instance from the IOC container
//output
"2"
```

###3. Default values
We can also pass in a default value which is returned if a parameter doesn't exist. It's much cleaner than a ternary expression that you'd normally use with the request globals

```
   //wrong way to do it in Laravel
   $page = isset($_POST['page']) ? $_POST['page'] : 1; 
   
   //do this instead
   $request->get('page', 1);
  
   //returns page 1 if there is no page
   //NOTE: This behaves like $_REQUEST array. It looks in both the
   //request body and the query string
   $request->input('page', 1);
```

###4. Using request function

```
$page = request('page', 1);
//returns page 1 if there is no page parameter in the query  string
//it is the equivalent of
$page = 1; 
if(!empty($_GET['page'])
   $page = $_GET['page'];
```

*The **default** parameter is optional therefore one can omit it*

###5. Using Request::query()

> While the input method retrieves values from entire request payload (including the query string), the query method will only retrieve values from the query string

```
//this is the equivalent of retrieving the parameter
//from the $_GET global array
$page = $request->query('page');

//with a default
$page = $request->query('page', 1);
```

###6. Using the Request [facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades)

```
$page = Request::get('page');

//with a default value
$page = Request::get('page', 1);
```

You can read more in the official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests

Answer (score 11):

We have similar situation right now and as of this answer, I am using laravel 5.6 release.

I will not use your example in the question but mine, because it's related though.

I have route like this:

```
Route::name('your.name.here')->get('/your/uri', 'YourController@someMethod');
```

Then in your controller method, make sure you include

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

and this should be above your controller, most likely a default, if generated using `php artisan`, now to get variable from the url it should look like this:

```
  public function someMethod(Request $request)
  {
    $foo = $request->input("start");
    $bar = $request->input("limit");

    // some codes here
  }
```

Regardless of the HTTP verb, the **input()** method may be used to retrieve user input.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input

Hope this help.

Answer (score 9):

This is the best practice. This way you will get the variables from 
GET method as well as POST method

```
    public function index(Request $request) {
            $data=$request->all();
            dd($data);
    }
//OR if you want few of them then
    public function index(Request $request) {
            $data=$request->only('id','name','etc');
            dd($data);
    }
//OR if you want all except few then
    public function index(Request $request) {
            $data=$request->except('__token');
            dd($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Query params are used like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends BaseController{

    public function index(Request $request){
         $param = $request->query('param');
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In laravel **5.3** `$start = Input::get('start');` returns `NULL`

To solve this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

//then inside you controller function  use

$input = Input::all(); // $input will have all your variables,  

$start = $input['start'];
$limit = $input['limit'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.3

I want to show the get param in my view

Step 1 : my route

```
Route::get('my_route/{myvalue}', 'myController@myfunction');
```

Step 2 : Write a function inside your controller

```
public function myfunction($myvalue)
{
    return view('get')->with('myvalue', $myvalue);
}
```

Now you're returning the parameter that you passed to the view

Step 3 : Showing it in my View

Inside my view you i can simply echo it by using

```
{{ $myvalue }}
```

So If you have this in your url

http://127.0.0.1/yourproject/refral/this@that.com

Then it will print this@that.com in you view file

hope this helps someone.

Comment: What you are using is not a get parameter but a URL fragment.

Comment: one day someone who needs a url fragment will be here. Its better to try than not. Thanks all the same for the info and downvote :x

Comment: You don't even explain that what you are using is not a get parameter. That's what the downvote is for.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question unfortunately

Comment: @The Dead Guy excellent, this is an excelent trick for me, upvote :D

Answer (score 0):

It is not very nice to use native php resources like `$_GET` as Laravel gives us easy ways to get the variables. As a matter of standard, whenever possible use the resources of the laravel itself instead of pure PHP.

There is at least two modes to get variables by GET in Laravel (
Laravel 5.x or greater):

**Mode 1**

Route:

```
Route::get('computers={id}', 'ComputersController@index');
```

Request (POSTMAN or client...):

```
http://localhost/api/computers=500
```

Controler - You can access the `{id}` paramter in the Controlller by:

```
public function index(Request $request, $id){
   return $id;
}
```

**Mode 2**

Route:

```
Route::get('computers', 'ComputersController@index');
```

Request (POSTMAN or client...):

```
http://localhost/api/computers?id=500
```

Controler - You can access the `?id` paramter in the Controlller by:

```
public function index(Request $request){
   return $request->input('id');
}
```