# Access query string values from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, query-string, laravel-routing

Does anyone know if it's possible to make use of URL query's within Laravel.

**Example**

I have the following route:

```
Route::get('/text', 'TextController@index');
```

And the text on that page is based on the following url query:

```
http://example.com/text?color={COLOR}
```

How would I approach this within Laravel?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Try this:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    return "<h1>" . Input::get("color") . "</h1>";
});
```

and call it by going to `http://example.com/test?color=red`.

You can, of course, extend it with additional arguments to your heart's content. Try this:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    return "<pre>" . print_r(Input::all(), true) . "</pre>";
});
```

and add some more arguments:

```
http://example.com/?color=red&time=now&greeting=bonjour`
```

This will give you

```
Array
(
    [color] => red
    [time] => now
    [greeting] => bonjour
)
```

Comment: why make use of Input object over the Request object in this example?

Comment: @MattCatellier I believe the request object is for Laravel version >= 5.0

Comment: Dont forgot add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` near imports

Answer (score 62):

For future visitors, I use the approach below for `> 5.0`. It utilizes Laravel's [`Request` class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests) and can help keep the business logic out of your `routes` and `controller`.

**Example URL**

```
admin.website.com/get-grid-value?object=Foo&value=Bar
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('get-grid-value', 'YourController@getGridValue');
```

**YourController.php**

```
/**
 * $request is an array of data
 */
public function getGridValue(Request $request)
{
    // returns "Foo"
    $object = $request->query('object');

    // returns "Bar"
    $value = $request->query('value');

    // returns array of entire input query...can now use $query['value'], etc. to access data
    $query = $request->all();

    // Or to keep business logic out of controller, I use like:
    $n = new MyClass($request->all());
    $n->doSomething();
    $n->etc();
}
```

For more on retrieving inputs from the request object, [read the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input).

Comment: It's $request->query('object'); for query string params.

Answer (score 11):

Query params are used like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ColorController extends BaseController{

    public function index(Request $request){
         $color = $request->query('color');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function fetchQuery(Request $request){
  $object = $request->query('object');
  $value = $request->query('value');
}
```