# Laravel method get pass variable

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-4.2

Here is my view to search from the laravel application..

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'get', 'url' => 'search'))}}
<input type="text" name="location" >
<input type="text" name="query" >
<input type="submit" >
{{ Form::close() }}
```

While i type something and press enter the page is taking me

Then My url is like this

```
myapp.com/search?query=abc&location=uk
```

How can i write the route to get the url values inside my controller ? 
Help pls

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744825/laravel-queries-strings

Comment: Thanks . My url is like `myapp.com/search?query=abc&location=uk`

Comment: That answer helps me only if i have like this `myapp.com/search/abc`

Comment: The answer which is added by Imtiaz Pabel is correct. You'll get exact result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that your route will be

```
Route::get('/search',yourController@controllerMethod)
```

Then go to your defined class and write a method which you mentioned in route

```
public function controllerMethod(){
 dd(Request::all());
}
```

within the request all you will get all params data

Comment: Thanks, but i am getting this error `Missing argument 1 for PublicController::search()`

Comment: I have the url like this `Route::get('/search','PublicController@search');` then in controller like this `public function search($query)
    {
            return Input::all();
    }`

Comment: But the error is like this always.. `Missing argument 1 for PublicController::search()`

Comment: Remove $query from search($query)