# Laravel a tag using href and html

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have an a tag that has `href="/test"`.  This sends me to my routes page and goes to a controller and everything works.  What I am wondering is if there is a way to attach a variable to `/test` that is from a html input tag the user inserted data into.  For example I will have an input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" id="number" placeholder="e.g. 1">
```

and I want my href to be `href="/test/" number`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Queries Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744825/laravel-queries-strings)

Comment: @Spartacus ; it's reversed as given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript for this at `onsubmit` or call any function on button click . And inside function use below code

```
 var number = 1;// Get value here from text box as $("#number").val();
 location.href ="/test/"+number;
```