# how to make two or more url in Laravel Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I want to make url like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/edit_1=1&edit_2=2` to pass to my controller

I try route like this `Route::get('post/edit_1={id}&edit_2={id2}', 'PostController@index')->name('post.index');`

and View like this `<a href="{{ route('post.index', '$id', '$id2') }}">Click Here</a>`

But I always got error, can someone fix my code

Comment: Use `/` instead `=` and `&`

Comment: 1st - you can't declare `GET` parameters in your route definitions, 2nd - `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/edit_1=1&edit_2=2` is a mix of what it seems like 2 `GET` parameters, but it doesn't start with `?`, so it's incorrectly formatted 3. - if you get an error, post what the error says

Comment: devk is right you should you proper route and url to match.

Comment: Your url should be like  http://127.0.0.1:8000/post?edit_1=1&edit_2=2   Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/24745203/6429700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think a simple route like this

```
Route::get('post/{1}/{2}', 'PostController@index')->name('post.index')
```

and call

```
<a href="{{ route('post.index', ['$id','$id2'] )}}">Click Here</a>
```