# Which url has to be put in AUTH callback url in bigcommerce

Tags: php, laravel, bigcommerce

Which URL has to be put in the AUTH callback URL, while making the app for Bigcommerce api?

When I click on my draft app its showing nothing.

I am using this url right now:

https://we-apps.com/disstem/public/bigcommerce/auth

https://we-apps.com/disstem/public/bigcommerce : its the path of my file.

Note: I am using laravel framework

My controller file

```
public function bigcommerce()
{
   $user_id = Auth::id();
   $header =  array(
      "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
   ); 

   $client_id = 'xxxx';
   $client_secret = 'xxxxx';
   $redirect_uri = 'https://w- ap.com/dis/public/bigcommerce';
   $postfields = array(
      "client_id" => $client_id,
      "client_secret" => $client_secret,
      "redirect_uri" => $redirect_uri,
      "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
      "code" =>$_GET['code'],
      "scope" => $_GET['scope'],
      "context" => $_GET['context'],
   );

   $postfields = http_build_query($postfields);
   $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/token');
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
         curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0 );
         curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
         curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
         curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
         curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
   $response = curl_exec( $ch );
   $result = json_decode($response);
   print_r($response);
```

my route file

```
 Route::get('/bigcommerce', 'IntegrationController@bigcommerce')->name('bigcommerce')->middleware('auth');
```

my laravel url to run this code is :

```
 https://w- ap.com/dis/public/bigcommerce
```

bigcommerce My APP callback url i have given is : same as my laravel url

```
https://w- ap.com/dis/public/bigcommerce
```

but its giving the error of **'code' is undefined.** . but when i click on install button of the app in bigcommerce its giving me back code,context and scope on and showing it on the bigcommerce but when i run my laravel code its giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

The auth callback URL should match whatever route you've defined in your app to respond to the [GET request](https://developer-beta.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/building-apps-bigcommerce/building-apps#building-apps_recieving-get-request) (triggered when your draft app's Install button is clicked within the control panel).

Here's an example from the BC sample PHP app, where `'/auth/callback'` is the route that's been registered:
https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex/blob/master/index.php#L37

In that case, the auth callback URL would be https://myapp.com/auth/callback

If you're using Laravel as your framework, the [syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#basic-routing) is a little different, but the concept is the same. Defining a route in your app tells the app to listen for an http request (in this case, a GET) to a specific URL (/auth/callback). When your app detects that a GET request has been sent to /auth/callback, then it will run the callback function you specify to handle the http request.

In the case of installing a BigCommerce app, that callback function should receive the temp auth code, context, and scopes from the GET request and then create a POST back to the BigCommerce auth service to exchange these for a permanent Oauth token (at that point, you store the token and the app shows 'installed' in the control panel). That's exactly what the callback function is doing [here](https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex/blob/master/index.php#L37).

**Edit:**
It looks like the syntax for handling the GET parameters isn't consistent with what the [Laravel docs recommend](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input):

$code = $request->query('code');

You might find the answer here helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34642837/8521556

Comment: sorry i am quite not understanding this part ' The auth callback URL should match whatever route you've defined in your app'.

Comment: @deep I edited my answer to add a few more details :) Let me know if it helps!

Comment: OK, I understood, then can you see my code what a little for better understanding. i am editing my question a little.

Comment: Could you try running var_dump on $postfields to see how the array is being built (and check to make sure the `code` is populating correctly)?

Comment: Could you share the full GET request URL with the code, context and scope params?

Comment: this is all i have no url to GET the code. this is what i am asking.

Comment: I mean the GET request that BigCommerce sends when your app's Install button is clicked. If you open the Network tab in your browser console, you'll see something like GET `https://w- ap.com/dis/public/bigcommerce?code=qr6h3thvbvag2ffq&scope=store_v2_orders&context=stores/g5cd38`. This would be helpful to make sure that you've registered the correct callback URL in dev tools and that your app is handling the URL parameters properly.

Comment: One more suggestion: you might want to try updating the syntax for how you're handling the GET parameters. I'll edit my post to include more details.