# How to get the key value pair param from a route

Tags: laravel

How do I get the key-value pair from a route like this `https://www .domain.com/path?param=x`
without using this `{param?}` the get route?

Comment: `$val = $request->param ??  null;` or `$val = $request->input('param') ??  null;`

Comment: yea but what if I have a function that doesn't get the $request param?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access query string values from Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744825/access-query-string-values-from-laravel)

Answer (score -1):

You can use php global variables $_REQUEST to get the requested parameter. In above case you can use $_REQUEST['param']

```
$param=$_REQUEST['param'];
```