# How to redirect a laravel (5.3) Route with get parameters to other Route

Tags: laravel, redirect, parameters, routes, get

When someone types:

http://site/nota.php?id_nota=6

I need to get redirected to:

http://site/nota/6

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744825/access-query-string-values-from-laravel

Comment: I've tried that, but have this error message
Class 'Input' not found

I guess that's becuase of the laravel version ...

Comment: I'm trying this , but I've already got an error message<br/>
`code`<br/>
Route::get('nota.php', function ($request) {<br/>
<br/>
 $id_nota=$request->input('id_nota');<br/>
 return redirect('nota',$id_nota);<br/>
<br/>
})->name('notaphp');<br/>
`code`<br/>
error msg returns:<br/>
Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\Router::{closure}(), 0 passed in ...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php on line 189 and exactly 1 expected

Answer (score 1):

Well I have a solution, is not pure laravel but works

```
Route::get('/nota.php', function () {
    $id_nota = $_GET['id_nota'];

    return redirect()->route('nota', [$id_nota]);
})->name('notaphp');
```