# Retrieving get parameters from URL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I created an URL String:

```
http://SERVER/v1/responders?latitude=48.25969809999999&longitude=11.43467940000005
```

a route:

```
Route::get('/responders', 'Responders\APIResponderController@index');
```

and a controller:

```
public function index(Request $request) {

    // Get Latitude and Longitude from request url
    $latitude = $request["latitude"];
    $longitude = $request["longitude"];

    $responders = new Responder();

    if(!isset($latitude) & !isset($longitude)) {
    }
```

But the result is not what I expected. The parameters in the URL string are not being parsed withing the controller. Do I parse them in a wrong way?

I tried to dump my input with `dd($request->all());` but the output is NULL. As the URL is sent correctly, I wonder where the data gets lost. Is my route file incorrect?

**Update**
Could it be my nginx config??

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/mfserver/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    charset utf-8;

    server_name SERVER;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www/mfserver/public;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting GET "?" variable in laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081090/getting-get-variable-in-laravel)

Comment: could you do a `dd($request->all())` and show the results?

Comment: The result is:
`array:1 [▼
  "query_string" => ""
]`

Comment: This is strange, as I definitely have the URL as mentioned above which should give the parameters

Comment: Sorry didn't find anything in your nginx config. And yeah I asked you to run dd(request()->get('latitude')) request as helper function without $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your nginx config. In your `location` definition, your `query_string` variable is missing the leading `$`. Because of this, your original query string is getting re-written with the plain text of `query_string`. This is why your request data is showing `array:1 [▼ "query_string" => "" ]` when you dump it.

Update your config to:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$inputs = $request->all();`

And then :

`$latitude = $inputs['latitude']`

`$longitude = $inputs['longitude']`

Comment: When I `var_dump` the inputs I get: `array(1) { ["query_string"]=> string(0)}`

Comment: Ok try just this dd(request()->all() and tell me what you are getting

Comment: The result is:
`array:1 [▼
  "query_string" => ""
]`

Comment: Strange O.o seriously

Comment: Yep... thats what I thought: I tried it out in the browser and in postman. Both the same result

Comment: This returns: "Undefined index Latitude"

Comment: So it's simple you are not getting this :D tell me what is v1 doing here? Why isn't it in your route or is it in your namespace?

Comment: That is a group I created and works well. But I have strange feeling it could be my nginx config.. I put it in my questions. Maybe this helps you?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, adapt it to your needs.

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    if(!$request->has('latitude') || !$request->has('longitude')) {
        // code if one or both fields are missing
    }

    // Get Latitude and Longitude from request url
    $latitude = (float)$request->input('latitude') ;
    $longitude = (float)$request->input('longitude');

    // other code here
```

}

Comment: when I do this: `$latitude = (float)$request->input('latitude');` the result is null

Answer (score 0):

The most common way would be

```
$latitude = $request->input("latitude");
```

Comment: this is strange... the output is NULL

Comment: Are you sure latitude was sent? You can see all attributes from the current request like this:
dd($request->all());

Comment: Interesting.. it is empty! But my URL String contains it
`http://SERVER/v1/responders?latitude=48.25969809999999&longitude=11.43467940000005
`
Do I need to change my routes file?