# Laravel - add to GET parameter manually

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way of adding to the GET parameter in Laravel, so that I can use

```
$request->input('param')
```

I've tried setting it in $_GET and did not pick up.
Basically I want to set something in to the HTTP Request's GET parameter set, so that I can retrieve it as if it was pass in as a GET params. (Which is sometimes sent)

Comment: can you clarify your question a little bit, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting GET "?" variable in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081090/getting-get-variable-in-laravel)

Comment: Added bit more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add params to your Request $request object like this

```
public function missingSomeParam(Request $request)
{
    // let's think you don't have "name" param sent in $request
    // set it this way
    $name = "Dummy Name";
    $request->request->add(['name' => $name]);
    dd($request->all());
}
```